# Convert datestamp from XML file

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a Google map application that displays data from an XML file. When you mouse over something it returns some info including data. The date from the XML file is like this...

```
  <cap:expires>2013-05-02T00:00:00-05:00</cap:expires>
```

I have this bit of code that converts it....

```
function dateFromString(s) {

  var bits = s.split(/[-T:+]/g);
  var d = new Date(bits[0], bits[1]-1, bits[2]);
  d.setHours(bits[3], bits[4], bits[5]);

  // Get supplied time zone offset in minutes
  var offsetMinutes = bits[6] * 60 + Number(bits[7]);
  var sign = /\d\d-\d\d:\d\d$/.test(s)? '-' : '+';

  // Apply the sign
  offsetMinutes = 0 + (sign == '-'? -1 * offsetMinutes : offsetMinutes);

  // Apply offset and local timezone
  d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - offsetMinutes - d.getTimezoneOffset())

  // d is now a local time equivalent to the supplied time
return (d);

} 

var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
var months =['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
var ampm = " am";

var dt = (dateFromString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));
var yr = dt.getFullYear();
var mth = dt.getMonth();  // months in Javascript are 0-11 so May is month 4
mth = months[mth];
var dte = dt.getDate();
var dy = dt.getDay();  // days are 0-6
dy = days[dy];
var hrs = dt.getHours();
var h1 = hrs;
var mins = dt.getMinutes();

if (hrs >= 12) {ampm = " pm"}
if (hrs >= 13) {hrs = hrs - 12}
if (h1 == 0) {hrs = 12}

if (hrs <10) {hrs = "0" + hrs};  // if  leading zero desired
if (mins <10) {mins = "0" + mins};

var dtstring = dy + " " + mth + " " + dte + " " + yr + " " + hrs + ":" + mins + ampm;
```

Which works great when you hard code this it converts it.

```
var dt = (dateFromString( '2013-05-02T11:08:00-6:00'));
```

My problem is how and where do I insert the element from the XML so it knows what to convert? I have it set up to output, I am just not sure where to put in the input for it to convert. I have included links to both the map and the xml file in case anyone needs to see the full code to see how it's all set up.

[DEMO MAP](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/googlemap_poly.html)

[DEMO XML](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/xml/warnings_test.xml)

Comment: Thanks but, where do I insert the element from the XML file that needs to be converted? Like I said I am not fluent in Js and hardly use it. -Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There  is a special class in Java to deal with XML dateTime javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2013-05-02T00:00:00-05:00");
```

Now use its methods to get necessary fields. You can also convert it to GregorianCalendar and Date